# How to transpose columns to rows where $1 fields are the same?

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

I have a file with two columns:

```
PLEKHN1   1:901922:G:A
PLEKHN1   1:901923:C:A
PLEKHN1   1:902088:G:A
HES4   1:934735:A:C
HES4   1:934770:G:A
```

I want to transpose columns to rows wherever the fields in `$1` are the same, while keeping only the first occurrence of `$1` value for each transposed group.

`Desired output:`

```
PLEKHN1   1:901922:G:A   1:901923:C:A   1:902088:G:A
HES4   1:934735:A:C   1:934770:G:A
```

Thank you.

Comment: Will they always be in a block or can the input be like `foo\t123\nbar\t123\nfoo\t345\n`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -lane'
  $k = shift @F;
  $s{$k} or push @r, $k;
  push @{$s{$k}}, @F;
  END {
    $" = "\t";
    print "$_\t@{$s{$_}}" for @r;
  }
' file
```

output

```
PLEKHN1 1:901922:G:A    1:901923:C:A    1:902088:G:A
HES4    1:934735:A:C    1:934770:G:A
```

Answer (score 2):

If data is grouped together in bulks you can do:

```
awk 'f!=$1 {printf RS$1} {printf "\t%s",$2;f=$1}' file

PLEKHN1 1:901922:G:A    1:901923:C:A    1:902088:G:A
HES4    1:934735:A:C    1:934770:G:A
```

If a blank line at the start is important to not get and a return at last hit, use this:

```
awk 'f!=$1 {printf (NR==1?"":RS)"%s",$1} {printf "\t%s",$2;f=$1} END {print ""}' file
PLEKHN1 1:901922:G:A    1:901923:C:A    1:902088:G:A
HES4    1:934735:A:C    1:934770:G:A
```

Answer (score 2):

If order is important then you can try something like:

```
awk '$1==p{l=l", "$2; next}{if(p) print p,l; p=$1;l=$2}END{print p,l}' file
```

This assumes that you won't have first column out of order.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you could say:

```
gawk '{o=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) o = o $i "\t"; a[$1]=a[$1] o;} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' OFS='\t' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
HES4    1:934735:A:C    1:934770:G:A
PLEKHN1 1:901922:G:A    1:901923:C:A    1:902088:G:A
```

Comment: Thank you. It works nicely! Is there anyway to keep the order of first column in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Perl solution.

Just put all the values into a hash and then read it back.

If you need to maintain the order of the values in the first column then it is a simple modification to add an array of keys to remember this order.

This program expects the path to the input file as the first parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
while (<>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split;
  push @{ $data{$key} }, $val;
}

while (my ($key, $vals) = each %data) {
  print join('   ', $key, @$vals), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
HES4   1:934735:A:C   1:934770:G:A
PLEKHN1   1:901922:G:A   1:901923:C:A   1:902088:G:A
```

---

**Update**

Perl hashes are inherently unordered. To maintain the keys in the order they appear in the original file, you can simply keep a list of new keys as they are read. This revised program demonstrates.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my @keys;
while (<>) {
  my ($key, $val) = split;
  push @keys, $key unless $data{$key};
  push @{ $data{$key} }, $val;
}

for my $key (@keys) {
  my $vals = $data{$key};
  print join('   ', $key, @$vals), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
PLEKHN1   1:901922:G:A   1:901923:C:A   1:902088:G:A
HES4   1:934735:A:C   1:934770:G:A
```

Comment: Thank you. It works nicely. Is there any way to keep the order of lines the same?

Comment: tell me again that you're not down voting me.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '
1 h
1 !{H;g;s/\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\(.*\)\n\1 \{1,\}/\1 \2 /;t same
   P;s/.*\n//
:same
   h;}
$ {x;p;}' YourFile
```

Assuming line are grouped by same 1st pattern as in your sample. You could have same 1st pattern in different non consecutive group, it will create separate line

(@user2162153) if 1 occurence in file, still work

```
$ cat YourFile
AtStart  0:123456789:A:A
PLEKHN1   1:901922:G:A
PLEKHN1   1:901923:C:A
PLEKHN1   1:902088:G:A
HES4   1:934735:A:C
HES4   1:934735:A:C
midle  5:934735:M:M
HES5   1:934735:A:C
HES5   1:934735:A:C
AtEnd  9:934735:Z:Z
$ sed -n '
> 1 h
> 1 !{H;g;s/\([^ ]\{1,\}\) \{1,\}\(.*\)\n\1 \{1,\}/\1 \2 /;t same
>    P;s/.*\n//
> :same
>    h;}
> $ {x;p;}' YourFile

AtStart  0:123456789:A:A
PLEKHN1 1:901922:G:A 1:901923:C:A 1:902088:G:A
HES4 1:934735:A:C 1:934735:A:C
midle  5:934735:M:M
HES5 1:934735:A:C 1:934735:A:C
AtEnd  9:934735:Z:Z
```

Comment: It prints the file in the current format. Would that work if some values in $1 appeared only once? Thank you!

Comment: It says `H: Event not found.`. I did not understand what I should do "add the session to post" ?

Comment: use maybe `-posix`and/or `-e` as option if GNU sed. the session is a copy of my session i just put in the previous reply

Comment: Thank you. I tried `-e` and/or `-posix`, but it still does not work.